# Magento 2: Send Email with CSV attachment

Tags: magento2, email, email-translation

How to send the simple mail with CSV attachment file in Magento 2.

Please help me to solve out this Question.

Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: did you tried the solution posted by me?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora, to be honest, I don't know how to send an email with CSV File and also I am confused with your code in where should I place the receiver email.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Magento (at the time of writing, I am using Magento version 2.2.7) does not provide the functionality to add an attachment in the email.

To add an attachment programmatically in the email, first, you need to override **\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder** class.

> **Step 1:** app/code/[Namespace]/[Module]/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" type="\[Namespace]\[Module]\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" />
</config>
```

> **Step 2:** app/code/[Namespace]/[Module]/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php

```
<?php

namespace Stream\EmailPrintableCsv\Mail\Template;

class TransportBuilder extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder {

    public function addAttachment(
    $filePath, $filename = null, $mimeType = \Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM, $disposition = \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, $encoding = \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64
    ) {
        if (file_exists($filePath)) {
            $body = file_get_contents($filePath);
            $this->message->createAttachment($body, $mimeType, $disposition, $encoding, $filename);
        }
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Now, you can call **addAttachment()** function while sending an email.

**Note:** addAttachment function requires 2 parameters: **filePath** and **fileName**.

Comment: But first, I don't know how to send the email in my cron class.

Comment: Please check my another question which is connected to this question, please help me if you have any idea(i.e. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/288206/magento-2-send-email-with-csv-attachment?noredirect=1#comment415171_288206 )

Comment: The link is redirecting to the same question.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/289415/magento-2-addattachment-is-not-working?noredirect=1#comment415288_289415

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an extension to allow you to attach a file to the contact form

Take a look at the controller

You might find it helpful

https://github.com/DominicWatts/ContactAttachment